# How to reject duplicate data and sort a JSON type object value using PHP

Tags: php, json

I need one help.I need to reject duplicate data ans sort the values present inside json object Using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
$res[]=array('member_name'=>$member,'no_of_members'=>$rowno['cnt'],'member_type'=>$countmemb);
```

The output of `$res` is given below.

```
[
  {member_name:"Medilink member",member_type:"1",no_of_members:"383"},
  {member_name:"Medilink member",member_type:"1",no_of_members:"383"},
  {member_name:"Medilink member",member_type:"1",no_of_members:"383"},
  {member_name:"Non-Medilink Member",member_type:"2",no_of_members:"24"},
  {member_name:"Non-Medilink Member",member_type:"2",no_of_members:"24"}

]
```

I need to reject the duplicate row from above and the result value format should come like below.

```
$res=[
    {member_name:"Medilink member",member_type:"1",no_of_members:"383"},
    {member_name:"Non-Medilink Member",member_type:"2",no_of_members:"24"}
]
```

I need the result like given above.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove duplicate records first from multidimensional array and than you can use `json_encode` for getting results in json format

```
<?
// your array
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Medilink member','no_of_members'=>1,'member_type'=>383);
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Medilink member','no_of_members'=>1,'member_type'=>383);
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Medilink member','no_of_members'=>1,'member_type'=>383);
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Non-Medilink member','no_of_members'=>2,'member_type'=>24);
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Non-Medilink member','no_of_members'=>2,'member_type'=>24);

// remove duplicates by using array_map and array_unique for multidimensional array
$duplicateRemoved = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $res)));

// rearrange the array
$rearrangeArray = array_values($duplicateRemoved);

// encode the unique array into json format    
$encodedData = json_encode($rearrangeArray);

// print result    
echo $encodedData;    
?>
```

Comment: @ devpro: ok,but in this way its index is coming different.i need all row index serially.

Comment: @satya: at the end it will return u this in json {"0":{"member_name":"Medilink member","no_of_members":1,"member_type":383},"3":{"member_name":"Non-Medilink member","no_of_members":2,"member_type":24}}   ---- 0 and 3 index

Comment: @ devpro : Yes,but i need index serially.

Comment: @satya: means rearrange the arrays 0,1

Comment: @satya: check update adding array_column for rearrange :)

Comment: happy coding my friend. @satya

Answer (score 0):

```js
// your array
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Medilink member','no_of_members'=>1,'member_type'=>383);
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Medilink member','no_of_members'=>1,'member_type'=>383);
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Medilink member','no_of_members'=>1,'member_type'=>383);
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Non-Medilink member','no_of_members'=>2,'member_type'=>24);
$res[]=array('member_name'=>'Non-Medilink member','no_of_members'=>2,'member_type'=>24);
$res = to_array_unique($res);
var_dump($res);exit;

function to_array_unique( $array ){
 $tmp_array = array();
 foreach( $array as $k => $v ){
  $tmp_array[] = json_encode($v);
 }
 $tmp_array = array_unique($tmp_array);

 $new_array = array();
 foreach ($tmp_array as $k2 => $v2) {
  $new_array[] = json_decode($v2);
 }
 return json_encode( $new_array );
}
```

Comment: I am not getting you.Please read my post again.I need to ignore the duplicate rows.

Comment: in this line `$tmp_array = [];` syntax error is coming.

Comment: maybe your php version is under 5.5? use $tmp_array = array();instand

Answer (score 0):

Check out [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). This built-in function throws out all of the duplicate entries.

I converted each line to a string, ex.: https://3v4l.org/LjBZS